# Join two tables - multiple conditions. Subsequent conditions to be used if not joined by prior conditions

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I am trying to build a join logic of two tables where I need to have a joining condition picked if in a manner ‘join by column 1, if not joined - by column 2, if not joined - by column 3’. I am having trouble building it in a simple way.

Just to give some background I try to find all products covered by contract. Sometimes products are explicitly mentioned in ProductId, but if the join fails (since wrong ProductId was supplied) I want to use Brand name to find all products under this brand and assume all of them are covered by contract. Brand name match will be less accurate so I want to use it only if I wasn’t able to find matching products by ProductId.

To illustrate, imagine I have two tables: Prosucts, with columns ProductId and BrandName; also table Contracts with table ContractId, Brand, ProductId, Value. For this table ProductId and Brand can be null or have values not in Products.

I want to join Contracts with Products such that:

- Try to left join where Contracts.ProductId=Products.ProductId
- For those entries in Contracts where join was not successful, join to Products where Contracts.Brand = Products.Brand
- If both join conditions were a failure - return null

Is there any way to make this sequential join logic where joining conditions are tried one by one? Just to highlight I have more than two joining conditions in reality. Thank you!

Example data:

**Contracts:**

```
ContractId  Brand   ProductId
C1  Mars    P1
C2  Nestle  P2
C3  PepsiCo P3
```

**Products:**

```
ProductId   Brand
P1  NULL
P2  Mars
P4  PepsiCo
P5  PepsiCo
```

**Expected Output**

```
ContractId  ProductId
C1  P1
C2  P2
C3  P4
C3  P5
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select p.productId, p.brandName, c.contractId 
from Products p left join Contracts c on
(p.productId = c.productId or p.productId=c.brand);
```

Here `or` clause will help you to get desired output.

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I understand it will be returning full set of potential matches by both first and second condition? The trick is, join by ProductId should take priority, and if we were able to find any matching records by ProductId than we don’t want to try join by Brand. Just to give some background I try to find all products covered by contract. Sometimes products are explicitly mentioned in ProductId, but if the join fails I want to use Brand name to find all products under this brand and assume all of them are covered by contract.

Comment: As per my understanding, short circuiting should take place here, ie if first condition is satisfied them second one won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using join of multiple instance of contracts table and `coalesce()` function

[DEMO:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=551fb07d8a8426e68dac10443fb958e3)

```
 select productid,coalesce(c.brand,b.brand) as brand 
    from Products a left join Contracts b on a.brand=b.brand 
    left join Contracts c on a.productid=c.productid
```